# ArcGIS Pro Export Map PDF with extra colored lines

Tags: arcgis-pro, pdf, layouts

I am exporting map to pdf using ArcGIS Pro at 600 dpi resolution. The exported map is coming with some thin colored lines.
I tried to export same map to png it appeared fine.

Am i missing something here regarding export settings for pdf ?

I have an interpolated raster these lines are reflecting the colors of that raster.

When i un-check that raster then it prints pdf fine.

I cannot include complete map screen shot but i am including the area where i dont have data. See the green lines in image.

[image]

When i select these blocks and right click i get the option to copy image. Seems like different small images have been stitched to generate this pdf.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this question although it is quite different (thick lines appear not thin lines)? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240124/is-pdf-version-exported-from-arcgis-pro-different-to-pdf-from-arcmap?rq=1

Comment: @ahmadhanb That was my first thought too.

Comment: No no, its not like this.
I am editing the question to include image

Comment: Have you tried removing the raster from the mxd and then uploading it again? It seems like there is a corruption occurring then translating to pdf and starting with a newly added layer has worked in the past.

Comment: Yes done that and even changed the symbology but still same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the issue is with the transparency of raster

https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5NTc2NQ==

Other issue is that ArcGIS Pro while exporting map to pdf do not have option to rasterize(ArcGIS Pro will get this in 2.3 version)

https://community.esri.com/ideas/14201-generalize-vector-data-on-export-settings

The **solution** of this problem is instead of sharing it as a pdf, Use the Print option print to file and while printing, Select Microsoft print to pdf. This results in rasterized map in pdf and it appears fine.

[image]

Update
Now you have the option in version 2.3

[image]

This resolves the issue

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 and this is still an issue.   Thankfully the Print to PDF option works.

Answer (score 0):

This still appears to be an issue in 2.8. The selected answer, Printing to PDF, is fine for users that do not need to utilize Python automation, but without an arcpy.mapping.PrintMap() parallel in ArcGIS Pro, this solution lacks some functionality.

A solution to this that also allows the use of ArcPy's layout.exportToPDF() is to set the base raster transparency to 0%. Then, create a polygon with a white fill that overlaps the entire area of interest, and set the transparency on the polygon layer. This seems to get rid of the grid lines.

This would not work well for multiple overlapping transparent rasters, however.